# Can't figure out these 2 problems on my CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation, css-animations

I have to make a css animation look exactly like [this example](https://youtu.be/tid7fRv4tGU)

Right now I am having major issues with these 2 aspects:

#1 - the arrow of my triangle needs to maintain a point aiming towards the circle, I have tried rotating it but only the edge of the triangle points to the circle

#2 - i need to create a slight increase in size (change-size code) for the circle, every time the triangle rotates past a specific part of the circle (it is subtle the change in size but you can see it in the video)

here is my code so far...

```css
svg {
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid navy;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 25vh);
}

.my-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  fill: navy;
  transform-origin: 200px 200px;
  animation: color-transition 8s ease-in-out infinite, rotate-triangle 5s linear infinite;
  scale: 0.2;
}

@keyframes rotate-triangle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, -795px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(0, -795px);
  }
}

@keyframes color-transition {
  0% {
    fill: navy;
  }
  16.6% {
    fill: peachpuff;
  }
  33.3% {
    fill: pink;
  }
  49.9% {
    fill: palevioletred;
  }
  66.4% {
    fill: plum;
  }
  83.7% {
    fill: purple;
  }
  100% {
    fill: navy;
  }
}

.my-circle {
  r: 18px;
  cx: 50%;
  cy: 50%;
  fill: navy;
  animation: color-transition 8s ease-in-out infinite, change-size 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes change-size {
  0% {
    r: 18px;
  }
  90% {
    r: 21px;
  }
  100% {
    r: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <circle class="my-circle" />
  <polygon class="my-triangle" points="200,75 300,225 100,225"/>
</svg>
```

I tried many things, I was thinking of perhaps trying to connect the circle and the triangle first whilst they are stationary, and then rotating the circle and having the triangle move with it.

I tried transform and translate in both HTML and CSS and I also tried version of rotate to change the triangle.

I am actually brain dead right now trying to figure this out. So I don't remember everything :/ sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of implementing this would be to have one rotating element which has the circle and triangle fixed within it.

In that way you are absolutely sure that they will remain in step with the triangle always pointing at the circle.

This snippet also uses CSS variables to set the color of the elements and the width of the circle. These can then be set in the same keyframes animation as the rotation of the element so we are sure changes are happening at the same time.

The snippet has exagerated the increase in size of the circle just so it can be easily seen. Obviously change this and the relative sizes and positionging of circle and triangle to what you require.

Rather than have the circle and triangle as images or separate elements they are drawn as before and after pseudo elements within the rotating element.

Here's what the initial set up looks like, with the container div given a border so you can see it.

[image]

```css
body {
  /* thse setting ust for the demo */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--width);
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: var(--color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
  background: magenta;
  background-color: var(--color);
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    --transform: rotate(0);
    --color: navy;
    --width: 10%;
  }
  16.6% {
    --color: peachpuff;
  }
  33.3% {
    --color: pink;
  }
  49.9% {
    --color: palevioletred;
  }
  66.4% {
    --color: plum;
    --width: 10%;
  }
  83.7% {
    --color: purple;
    --width: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    --color: navy;
    --width: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```